# Function to nearest power of 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, functions

Consider a function F(n) on postive integers that finds the nearest power of 2 in value to n, and then takes the absolute value of the difference. Repeat applying the function onto the resulting value, until you get 0. For example, F(10)=8-10=2, and then F(F(10))=F(2)=2-2=0.

What could be the longest streak of consecutive integers that require the same number of iterations of F to get to 0? I have tried to look for patterns, but nothing appears to be possible.

Is this provable by induction？

Answer (score 1):

Represent an integer in binary, e.g. (1010)2 for (10)10 in decimal.

A decimal 10, by two function calls, becomes 0.

1. 10-8=2
2. 2-2=0

Another example, such as decimal 27, its binary representation is (11011)2, call the function

1. 27-16=11
2. 11-8=3
3. 3-2=1
4. 1-1=0

Notice the pattern? Under binary representation, there are as many 1's as there are functions to call.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated. OP asks for the nearest power of $2$, not the nearest power of $2$ smaller than the chosen number. So for the example number $27$, $32$ is closer to $27$ than $16$, and the descent would go: $32-27=5; 5-4=1; 1-1=0$, which is three steps rather than four.